# Empirical CDF function in python with reasonable NaN behavior

Tags: python, numpy

I'm looking to compute the ECDF and am using this statsmodels function:

```
from statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution import ECDF
```

Looks good at first:

```
ECDF(np.array([0,1,2,3, 3, 3]))(np.array([0,1,2,3, 3,3]))
array([0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       , 1.        , 1.        ,
       1.        ])
```

However, nan seems to be treated as infinity:

```
>>> x = np.array([0,1,2,3, np.nan, np.nan])
>>> ECDF(x)(x)
array([0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       , 0.66666667, 1.        ,
       1.        ])
```

Same as:

```
np.array([0,1,2,3, np.inf, np.inf])
ECDF(x)(x)
array([0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       , 0.66666667, 1.        ,
       1.        ])
```

Comparing with R:

```
> x <- c(0,1,2,3,NA,NA)
> x
[1]  0  1  2  3 NA NA
> ecdf(x)(x)
[1] 0.25 0.50 0.75 1.00   NA   NA
```

What's the standard python function for ecdf that is nan aware?

Hot-wiring like so does not seem to work:

```
def ecdf(x):
  return np.where(~np.isfinite(x),
                  np.full_like(x, np.nan),
                  ECDF(x[np.isfinite(x)])(x[np.isfinite(x)]))

ecdf(x)
    ECDF(x[np.isfinite(x)])(x[np.isfinite(x)]))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in where
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (7,) (7,) (4,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/b2397a21cd9ffcf1f52593380816d3bdfd8a7f0d/statsmodels/distributions/empirical_distribution.py#L108-L145) of statsmodel's ECDF is pleasantly brief (after stripping comments):

```py
class ECDF(StepFunction):
    def __init__(self, x, side='right'):
        x = np.array(x, copy=True)
        x.sort()
        nobs = len(x)
        y = np.linspace(1./nobs,1,nobs)
        super(ECDF, self).__init__(x, y, side=side, sorted=True)
```

Sorting the input samples via `x.sort()` will move all the `np.nan` valued elements to the end even after `np.inf`, which is why they appear to be treated  as infinity

```py
bar=np.array([1, np.nan, 2, np.inf, 3])
bar.sort()
# bar is now array([ 1.,  2.,  3., inf, nan])
```

The reason `np.nan` isn't propagated is because ECDF's parent class uses `np.searchsorted` to find the correct index and then looks it up in `y`. For `np.nan` this is simply the last element of the array and a subsequent lookup of `self.y` will return 1 for this case.

You can make it propagate `np.nan` with a simple change, which you can realize as a subclass or sibling.

```py
from statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution import StepFunction
import numpy as np


class MyECDF(StepFunction):
    def __init__(self, x, side='right'):
        x = np.sort(x)

        # count number of non-nan's instead of length
        nobs = np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(x))

        # fill the y values corresponding to np.nan with np.nan
        y = np.full_like(x, np.nan)
        y[:nobs]  = np.linspace(1./nobs,1,nobs)
        super(MyECDF, self).__init__(x, y, side=side, sorted=True)
```

This small change will make the function behave in a way similar to R:

```py
>>> from foobar import MyECDF
>>> from statsmodels.distributions.empirical_distribution import ECDF
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([0,1,2,3, np.nan, np.nan])
>>> ECDF(x)(x)
array([0.16666667, 0.33333333, 0.5       , 0.66666667, 1.        ,
       1.        ])
>>> MyECDF(x)(x)
array([0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ,  nan,  nan])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a masked array:

```
import numpy.ma as ma

def ecdf(x):
  return np.where(np.isnan(x),
                  np.full_like(x, np.nan),
                  ECDF(ma.array(x, mask=np.isnan(x)).compressed(), "right")(ma.array(x, mask=np.isnan(x))),
)

>>> ecdf(x)
array([0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ,  nan,  nan])
```

Matches what R does natively.